# Is there a word for extreme classism?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there is a word that describes vehement disdain for people who are perceived to have a lower social status than one's self? I'm looking for a word that is to class-ism as bigotry is to racism.

Comment: It's called *elitism*.

Comment: @Robusto: I don't think elitism' is quite nearly as strong as 'racism', the same 'vehement disdain'.

Comment: But how about a disdain for people who are perceived to have a higher class than oneself? Class-hate can go both ways, and a hatred of upper classes is certainly not alien among radical communists or so. Or a hatred of the own class...

Comment: *[Bigotry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bigotry)*, although most often used of religious or racial intolerance or prejudice, can also be used of vehement classism.

Comment: What @jwpat7 is true...bigotry is not specific to racism.

Comment: Very good question. Intrenched classism is as rampant/more rampant than racism and there seem to be powerful taboos against any acknowledgement of its existence. One thinks of Orwells ever thinner dictionaries as concepts inimicable to the dominant class were removed. In this case there isnt't even a word in the first place. But there should be. Our societys' are saturated in class - as-racism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose the word that comes closest is *snobbery*.

Answer (score 3):

*Haughtiness* might work.

[*Haughty* (the adjective form) means](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=haughty) "having or showing arrogant superiority to and disdain of those one views as unworthy."

Comment: Haughtiness is to class as bigotry is to racism? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

*Bigotry* is to *classism* as *bigotry* is to *racism*.

That is because *bigotry* is not a racism-specific word. It originally criticized [sanctimonious](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sanctimonious) religious beliefs[¹](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bigot), and subsequently acquired a broader meaning.

*Bigotry* now refers to “the practice of having very strong and unreasonable opinions, especially about politics, race, or religion, and refusing to consider other people's opinions”.[²](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bigotry)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest *imperiousness*.